# jQuery .load Not Working In IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, load

I'm looking for some help with the following code, in which I'm trying to dynamically load some PHP content into a DIV:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
   $('#folders').load('loadfolders.php');
                  });
            });
</script>
```

This code works fine in FF and Safari, but will not work in IE7.

More specifically, it does not load anything into the DIV, it remains blank.

Interestingly, if I replace it with:

```
$('#folders').load('test.html');
```

It works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, figured this one out. User error.

:-(

Apparently, I had one too many

```
</div>
```

tags.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with loading images. Adding a time after the source says to IE: "you have to load it again, because it is not the same as it was last time!"

```
if($.browser.msie)
    cacheImage.src = src_array[i]+ "?" + new Date().getTime();else/*IE fix*/
        cacheImage.src = src_array[i];
```

source:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fixing-load-in-ie-for-cached-images